# File upload .NET Core 'IFormFile' does not contain a definition for 'CopyToAsync' and no extension method

Tags: c#, iformfile

I am using `CopyToAsync` for upload/download functionilities.

It is showing that that `List<IFormFile>` does not have this extension method.

What to do?

```
var result = new List<FileUploadResult>();
foreach (var file in formFile)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
        "wwwroot/files", formFile.FileName);
    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
    result.Add(new FileUploadResult()
    {
        Name = file.FileName,
        Length = file.Length
    });
}

return Ok(result);
```

Comment: Your code is not doing what you say it's doing.

Comment: You mean `file.CopyTo...`, not `formFile.CopyTo...`.

Answer (score 3):

List does not have that extension method. The IFormFile interface does, though.
Isn't this what you wanted to do?

```
var result = new List<FileUploadResult>();
foreach (var file in formFile)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
        "wwwroot/files", formFile.FileName);
    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    file.CopyToAsync(stream);
    result.Add(new FileUploadResult()
    {
        Name = file.FileName,
        Length = file.Length
    });
}

return Ok(result);
```